# UISearchDisplay crashes because of key value

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have a working Table view controller that populates based on xml files corresponding to the previous table view controller. Everything works just fine until I tried adding a `UISearchDisplayController.`

After going through some tutorials I tried implementing their code but my app keeps crashing with the below error:

** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<__NSCFString 0x175949e0> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key name.'
**

Here are some relevant code snippets for my .m file:

```objc
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        return self.searchResults.count;
    } else {
        return _Refs.SubReference.count;
    }      
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    SubRefCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"TableCell"forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell == nil) {
        NSLog(@"Error with nil cell");
    }

    int row=[indexPath row];

    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {

        cell.subRefLabel.text = self.searchResults[row];
        cell.subRefDescLabel.text = _Refs.SubRefDesc[row]; //fix later

    } else {
        //set all the cells with the Sub Reference names and their descriptions
        cell.subRefLabel.text = _Refs.SubReference[row];
        cell.subRefDescLabel.text = _Refs.SubRefDesc[row];
    }
    return cell;
}

#pragma Search Methods

- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
    NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name contains[c] %@", searchText];
    //self.searchSubRef = _Refs.SubReference;
    NSLog(@"Here is a list of refs %@",_Refs.SubReference);

    //crashes right after this line
    self.searchResults = [_Refs.SubReference filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
    NSLog(@"Test");        
}

-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{       
    [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString
                               scope:[[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles]
                                      objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar
                                                     selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];       
    return YES;
}
```

I do have custom cells and checked for '!' on all the outlets for both my tableview controller and my table view cell but they all seemed to be ok. I also tried to open the storyboard as source code and look for outlets called 'name' but no luck.

Any ideas what is going wrong and why the app crashes as soon as I try typing into the search bar?

Comment: Have you stepped through your code to see which line of code triggers the crash?

Comment: Yes it's commented in my code snippet above inside of `- (void)filterContentForSearchText:` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem was with my NSPredicate.
`NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name contains[c] %@", searchText];`

It is trying to look for a reusable cell identifier called `name` which I never declared. So a simple fix for this was to use `SELF` instead.

`NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[c] %@", searchText];`

Answer (score 0):

The problem appeared to be a missing UITableViewCell initialiser statement. You are dequeuing the tableview cell without creating it in first place.

You need following statement if the dequeue returns nil,

```
 if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"TableCell"];
 }
```

What if dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier returns nil, where are creating one?

Besides you are using different variants of initialiser for that you needs to register a class or nib file using the registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier: or registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier: method before calling the following method,

```
 [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"TableCell" forIndexPath:indexPath]
```

Register the nib in your viewDidLoad as follows

```
UINib *cellNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"SubRefCell" bundle:nil];
[myTable registerNib:cellNib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"TableCell"];
```

Comment: So I tried it with `cell = [[SubRefCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"TableCell"];` but I still get the same crash. That's why I had the NSLog to check if it was getting to cel==nil

Comment: Not exactly sure what `myTable` is suppose to be. Also, I'm using storyboard. Would that make a difference in the code?

Comment: So I tried `UINib *cellNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"SubRefCell" bundle:nil];`
`[self.tableView registerNib:cellNib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"TableCell"];`
but that crashes my app as soon as load into the table view controller with `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITableViewCell subRefLabel]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1469a020'`
I also tried `[self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"TableCell"];`
but that also crashes the app. I do have a custom tableviewcell. Would that make a difference?

Comment: don't use registerClass, use register nib.

Comment: it is quite harder to see what are doing, would be better if we can go through your project to see what's happening?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59545/discussion-between-ldindu-and-diegou).